# Store function reference in javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript, object-literal

I'm guessing this should be simple, but I'm stuck. How can I store a reference to a method in another prototype object (in this case `actions`)? In the manner below I get undefined for my someFn and anotherFn methods.

```
class MyClass

  constructor: ->
    console.log @actions # returns
    # returns:
    # Object {someFn: undefined, anotherFn: undefined, someText "I am some text"}

  actions:
     someFn: @someFn
     anotherFn: @anotherFn
     someText: 'I am some text'

  someFn: ->
    console.log 'I am some function'

  anotherFn: ->
    console.log 'I am another function'
```

I'm using CoffeeScript, but for any plain JSers our there -

```
  MyClass = function MyClass() {
    console.log(this.actions);
  }

  MyClass.prototype.actions = {
    someFn: MyClass.someFn,
    anotherFn: MyClass.anotherFn,
    someText: 'I am some text'
  };

  MyClass.prototype.someFn = function() {
    return console.log('I am some function');
  };

  MyClass.prototype.anotherFn = function() {
    return console.log('I am another function');
  };
```

Comment: `{someFn: MyClass.someFn, ...}`: `MyClass` doesn't have a property `someFn`. Did you expect this to "magically" work?

Comment: no I didn't expect it to magically work, that's why I'm asking a question.

Comment: Fair enough. It wasn't clear to me from the question whether you know why you are getting `undefined` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have objects on the prototype like that. You'll want to make that an instance property:

```
class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    @actions =
      someFn: @someFn
      anotherFn: @anotherFn
      someText: 'I am some text'
    console.log @actions # works as expected

  someFn: ->
    console.log 'I am some function'

  anotherFn: ->
    console.log 'I am another function'
```

If for some reason you really needed an object with the prototype functions on it, use `::` to access them (in the static context of creating the `action` object):

```
…
  someFn: …
  anotherFn: …
  actions:
     someFn: @::someFn
     anotherFn: @::anotherFn
     someText: 'I am some text'
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergie, that was an oversight on not referencing the protoypes in the actions object (the second approach you mentioned). That said, while the static method approach is cool and gets what I need, the second approach isn't working for me. I'm still getting undefined, any idea why?

Comment: Order of assignment matters. Notice how I've placed `actions` below the methods that it uses.